# Actionscript 3 modify Label Component text

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, label

I'm trying to modify the text of a Label component that I already placed on the stage in as3.
I'm having trouble getting the text to change though, it just stays the same based on the inital text I typed in. I'd like to eventually have the label contents change dynamically. When I compile the swf, the two labels have the original value I gave them when I  put them on the stage, not the startDate and endDate values. My code looks like:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import fl.controls.Slider; 
    import fl.events.SliderEvent; 
    import fl.controls.Label; 

    public class slider extends MovieClip{

        public var startDate:int;
        public var endDate:int;

        public function slider(){
            dateSlider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, changeHandler); 
            startDate = 1981;
            endDate   = 1995;
            startLabel.text = startDate.toString();
            endLabel.text   = endDate.toString();
        }

        private function changeHandler(event:SliderEvent):void { 
            yearLabel.text = (event.value/10) + startDate + " year";     
        }
     }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: is `slider` the document class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your are trying to change button label. Are you?

If yes, then do

startLabel.label = startDate.toString();
 instead of startLabel.text = startDate.toString();